# Intune (MDM) Win32 App - How to update the Version Number with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, intune

I go to "endpoint.microsoft.com", and I login

And I click on "Apps" on the left side

And I click on "All Apps" in the middle

And I see my Win32 app "Test App" displayed in the results.

I click on "Test App" and I see that it's been installed 16 times.  And its Version number is currently: 2.5

**How do I, with PowerShell, change its version number to 3?**

I have tried installing the module "Microsoft.Graph.Intune"

And after I run a `Connect-MSGraph` command

I run a `Get-IntuneMobileApp | where {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Test App'}`

And I'm able to see the App:

```
@odata.type                    : #microsoft.graph.win32LobApp
id                             : 75a18bff-aaa4-482a-8f04-440251482961
displayName                    : Test App
description                    : InstallPolicy.cmd
publisher                      : Sam P
largeIcon                      :
createdDateTime                : 9/23/2022 5:22:32 PM
lastModifiedDateTime           : 9/23/2022 6:21:57 PM
isFeatured                     : False
privacyInformationUrl          :
informationUrl                 :
owner                          :
developer                      : Sam P
notes                          :
publishingState                : published
committedContentVersion        : 1
fileName                       : InstallPolicy.intunewin
size                           : 432
installCommandLine             : InstallPolicy.cmd install
uninstallCommandLine           : InstallPolicy.cmd uninstall
applicableArchitectures        : x86,x64
minimumFreeDiskSpaceInMB       :
minimumMemoryInMB              :
minimumNumberOfProcessors      :
minimumCpuSpeedInMHz           :
msiInformation                 :
setupFilePath                  : InstallPolicy.cmd
minimumSupportedWindowsRelease : 1607
rules                          : {@{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.win32LobAppFileSystemRule; ruleType=detection;
                                 path=C:\Temp; fileOrFolderName=VTest.log.txt; check32BitOn64System=False;
                                 operationType=exists; operator=notConfigured; comparisonValue=}}
installExperience              : @{runAsAccount=system; deviceRestartBehavior=suppress}
returnCodes                    : {@{returnCode=0; type=success}, @{returnCode=1707; type=success}, @{returnCode=3010;
                                 type=softReboot}, @{returnCode=1641; type=hardReboot}...}
```

But I don't see its Version Number

**And how do I update its Version Number with PowerShell?**

When I update the app by hand, and change its Version Number, it kicks off a new set of installations of the latest version.

I'm trying to kick off that process with PowerShell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [GraphAPI Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-apps-win32lobapp) for `win32lobapp` apps, the version is the `ProductVersion` number pulled from the [MSI info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-apps-win32lobappmsiinformation?view=graph-rest-1.0) `win32LobAppMsiInformation` property:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.win32LobApp",
  "id": "String (identifier)",
  "displayName": "String",

  ...trimmed...

  "msiInformation": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.win32LobAppMsiInformation",
    "productCode": "String",
    "productVersion": "String",
    "upgradeCode": "String",
    "requiresReboot": true,
    "packageType": "String",
    "productName": "String",
    "publisher": "String"
  }
}
```

I don't have MDM apps to test with, but you should be able to see those properties with something like:

```
Get-IntuneMobileApp | 
  where {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Test App'} |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty msiInformation
```

If it returns blank then try running it in powershell v7+ (there are some improvements to JSON) and/or update the Graph module.

If the cmdlets aren't built out enough to update that property yet, you can always use [Invoke-MgGraphRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/authentication-commands?view=graph-powershell-1.0#using-invoke-mggraphrequest)